# What's mnt in misc in internal storage?

Tags: internal-storage, storage

On an Android device, checking storage in the normal system settings, it reports that only 7.9 MB out of 1.29 GB of internal storage is free. It lists 1.20 GB of Misc files.

Checking the misc files, there's a an entry `mnt` that makes up 1.20 GB. At first I thought that this was equivalent to /mnt, but looking more closely there's a mounted SD Card with 20.27 out of 29.71 GB free. So it shouldn't be the SD card.

- What is the mnt entry?
- Can it be safely be deleted to free up internal storage space?

*Further complicating issue: I'm helping a friend on travel on another continent, so I don't have direct access to the tablet.*

Comment: What is the location of the "misc" mnt file?

Comment: AFAIK I can't see the location from the storage menu.

Comment: How can you tell that there is 2 different "mnt" files/folders? Have you tried using any disk usage apps?

Comment: I can't tell, except that this one is listed under misc files in internal storage. No, haven't tried any disk usage apps. Anyone you recommend?

Comment: [Disk Usage & Storage Analyzer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mobile_infographics_tools.mydrive&hl=en&referrer=utm_source%3Dgoogle%26utm_medium%3Dorganic%26utm_term%3Ddisk+usage+%26+storage+apk&pcampaignid=APPU_1r-JVIHJMcafNqTdgZAE) It's free and no ads

Comment: Did you tap on misc in internal storage in device settings? It should show the files in there. But try the link